# Actionbar logo turns in app icon on an expanded ActionView

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am hitting quite a few obstacles styling the `ActionBar`.

The problem I am having now is the logo/icon when an `ActionView` is expanded.
For some reason it doesn't use the logo drawable here but the app icon drawable. I want this either gone or set to my own drawable. I tried setting the icon directly in the `onMenuItemActionCollapse()` using the `setIcon()` function of `ActionBar` with no luck. Also tried setting the home and logo stuff in there.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: having the same issue. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it, although no where documented, when i was going through the source i saw it actually uses the icon instead of the logo. What i also found is that there is an attribute called `icon` in the `actionBarStyle`. So the following works:

```
<style name="action_bar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/logo</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
</style>
```

Comment: yea, but what if you logo is different than your icon such as the youtube app?

Comment: Then you're out of luck i'm afraid. The only other solutions is to hide the up and icon indicator and place a custom view there

Comment: I found if I set it programmatically the issue goes away. Looks like a dumb bug.

Comment: @user123321 it doesn't force you to use the same logo — you are setting the icon in the action bar style, not in the "root" style

Answer (score 0):

So, I came across the same problem and fixed it this way:

1. Make sure you have proper drawables for your logo. I used Android Asset Studio to do this.
2. In your manifest, under `application`, make sure you specify your icon and logo.
3. In your activity (or, in my case, fragment) set the ActionBar's icon to the logo using `setIcon`.

When I dealt with this, #3 "worked" for me, but the icon ended up being a smaller version of what was used in the ActionBar, so I made sure I had proper sizes in my app (which I didn't at the time).